# In a Browser, Break on Window Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, prototype, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Devtools, you can break javascript on changing a DOM element's attributes, or on subtree modifications of an element.

I'm working on some legacy code that has some javascript that scrolls to the top of the page under certain situations, and I want to find the JS that does this.

Is there a way, in Devtools, so break on scroll events?

It could be jQuery or Prototype.js or event base JS that does it, and I've searched the codebase for .scrollTop or .animate, and I've found plenty of those, but none that are causing my issue.

Comment: Have you searched for window.scrollTo or window.scroll?

Comment: Yea I've searched for those, and they show up, but none of them are for the page I'm on.

Comment: You might be able to see it with visual event http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event

Comment: Does **Event Listener Breakpoints > Control > Scroll** do what you want? Or does that only fire if the page is scrolled by the user, not code?

Comment: ^ This worked. Thanks Barmar! Submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Barmar Yes and no. It breaks when the window is scrolled programmatically, but it breaks inside the *event listener*, so you can't see what bit of code actually scrolled the page.

Comment: Firefox debugger > Events tell you wich line of code is that triggers each event.

Answer (score 6):

I have no additional idea about actually breaking than the ones presented.

But i suspect it is not scrolling that causes the issue, but a '#' in the html.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">x</a>
```

is a very common pattern. when you forget (or something prevents) the "return false", the # (empty anchor) will be navigated to, which causes a scroll to top.

Check if the url has a # at the end after clicking!

Comment: It's because `<a href="#">` it's bad practice, even if everybody makes it. Better `<a href="javascript:;">`  or better `<a href="javascript:void(0);">` and you not need never to guess if you need to prevent default action or return something to prevent execute the anchor (because `#` it's an empty anchor!).

Comment: yes it is bad practice. however i see myself still doing it. when i have a good day, i use `<b>x</b>`. you can add handlers and style it however you like and the code is even shorter. i dont care much for the javascript:... solutions as they add complexity to reading the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can inject this line of JS using the console to trigger the debugger when the scroll position changes programatically.

```
window.__defineSetter__("pageYOffset", function(){
    debugger;
});
```

Then, view the call stack to see what triggered it.

If you don't want to activate the debugger, you can print the stack trace istead with the following code:

```
window.__defineSetter__("pageYOffset", function(){
    console.log(new Error().stack);
});
```

Another option is to replace the windows `scroll`, `scrollTo` and `scrollBy` method with your own.

```
window.__defineGetter__('scroll', function(){
  console.log('window.scroll getter :' + new Error().stack);
  return function(x,y){
    debugger; //or print stack trace
    oldScroll(x,y);
  }
});
```

Repeat for `scrollTo` and `scrollBy`.

Comment: I dumped that debugger line in the console and nothing came up when I clicked the scrolling button.

Comment: @Josh Did you try replacing the `scroll`, `scrollTo` and `scrollBy` methods?

Comment: Tried defining all getters and did not see output in console...Using Chrome (latest). When I output the function def in console (ie. type fn name and Enter) I do see the new fn def. Invoking `scroll`, eg, throws 2 errors: `window.scroll getter :Error
    at <anonymous>:3:42
    at <anonymous>:1:1
window.scroll getter :Error
    at <anonymous>:5:44
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: @seebiscuit, those errors are exactly what's included in the code samples from the answer. When running it from the console you will get this generic error message.  But if the scroll is called programatically from a script on the page, you will get an appropriate stack trace.

Comment: Excellent! Just when I thought I had ECMAScript 3 down cold ;) Thanks for the education!